# Symfony/Monolog: Custom processor with FOSUserBundle data

Tags: php, symfony, oop, dependency-injection, monolog

I'd like to add the `userId` and `username`, provided by `FOSUserBundle`, to my Logger (Monolog). I followed [this tutorial](http://www.petethompson.net/blog/symfony/2015/03/15/symfony-logging-client-ip/) to be able to log the IP, it's working.

My code below breaks, because `$this->tokenStorage->getToken()` is `NULL`, even if I'm logged in.

**services.yml**

```
monolog.processor.user:
    class: AppBundle\Log\UserProcessor
    arguments: [ "@request_stack", "@security.token_storage" ]
    tags:
      - { name: monolog.processor }
```

**AppBundle/Log/UserProcessor.php**

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
use AppBundle\Entity\User;

class UserProcessor
{
    private $requestStack;
    private $tokenStorage;

    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack, TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }

    public function __invoke(array $record)
    {
        $username = '';
        $userId   = 0;
        $user     = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();

        // !!! ERROR !!!
        // $this->tokenStorage->getToken() is NULL

        if ($user instanceof User) {
            $username = $user->getUsername();
            $userId   = $user->getId();
        }

        $record['extra']['user_id']  = $userId;
        $record['extra']['username'] = $username;

        return $record;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would say that the problem probably is that the processor is called to log something before security has been able to act and get the current user. There is very little you can do if that is the case, just check if token exists and if it doesn´t don't log user

Comment: @CarlosGranados Looks like, you're right. Makes sense! I successfully tested the processor with a custom handler/channel which I called in controllers (where security is accessible). Just post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the processor is called to log something before security has been able to act and get the current user. Just check if token exists and if it doesn´t don't log user